# What is wrong with my Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my jsfiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/mZGsp/). I was trying to answer a question here but my code won't work. Here is the code:

### JS

```
var stateOfClick = null;

function initiateLine(){
    document.getElementById('test').innerHtml = "Started";
}

function endLine(){
    document.getElementById('test').innerHtml = "Line Ended";
}

function createLines(){
  if(!stateOfClick) {
    initiateLine();
    stateOfClick = 1;
  } else {
    endLine();
  }
}
```

### HTML

```
<body>
    <input type="text" id="test" onclick="createlines()">
</body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of things,

- change `createlines()` to `createLines` (camel-case).
- change `<element>.innerHtml` to `<element>.value`
- Inside JSFiddle, don't wrap your code inside a function, as then `createLines` won't be global which it needs to be for the `onclick` to work.

Here's a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/anurag/WpLG3/).

Answer (score 2):

Not even [this simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/UmeXe/) will work on jsFiddle. You need to attach the event listener with JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("someElement").onclick = function() {
  //Do stuff  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For input element you must use the value attribute not the innerHTML field.

```
function initiateLine(){
    document.getElementById('test').value = "Started";
}
```

also you've misspelled the innerHTML function (though not the primary problem). innerHTML is used for html elements that can contain other elements such as a div containg a p element. Input and option elements all have a value attribute that can be used to extract or set their values.

Comment: the input element click handler is miss typed